# Comprehensibility of a question

Tags: discussion

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/definition-of-curriculum

Why is the question above, which is so readily comprehensible to those who post to matheducators.stackexchange.com/, so incomprehensible to those who post to academia.stackexchange.com that they closed it as "not clear what you're asking"? (One of those who voted to close had an ulterior motive, shown by the fact that under the question he expressed anger about an opinion I had expressed on a different topic on a different occasion. He identified himself as one of those who thought the question was unclear.  But it takes more than one to close a question.)

Comment: I cast the final close vote on your now deleted question. Had you edited it here, I would have voted/nominated it for reopening. I think it is as simple as your original wording was unclear and your new wording is clear.

Answer (score 11):

On Math Educators, you wrote:

> **Definition of "curriculum"**
>
> In standard usage does the word "curriculum" mean
>
> - That which ought to be taught and learned, as prescribed by authorities (i.e. teachers and textbook authors and the like); or
> - That which actually *is* taught and learned in conventional practice, regardless of whether it is consistent with what authorities say ought to be taught and learned; or
> - Something else?

On Academia, you wrote:

> **What is a curriculum?**
>
> The concept of "curriculum" seems to include prescriptive as opposed to descriptive lists of topics, i.e. things that ought to be taught and learned over the course of a term or of sequence of terms.
>
> Does it also included descriptive lists of topics that actually are taught and learned in widespread and enduring practice?
>
> Would that also be called a curriculum?

and later, after the question was closed, you added

> Primarily this question is about how this terminology is conventionally understood.

Often, the phrasing of a question plays a large role in its comprehensibility. While these two may seem equivalent to you, as the person who wrote the question, **you** have a head start in understanding what **you** mean.

I don't think it's unreasonable to conclude that significant differences in the way a question is phrased can have a significant effect on how clear it is to readers.